# I can't find where I make mistake in this "L'hospital like rule" derivation

Tags: limits, functions, derivatives

I've been playing around with L'hospital's rule and I've run into this "error".
Suppose that we have two functions $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ for which $f,g:\mathbb R\rightarrow \mathbb R$ which are $C^1$ at an interval (-$\delta+x_0,x_0+\delta $). Suppose that $\lim_{x\to x_0}f(x)=l_1$ and  $\lim_{x\to x_0}g(x)=l_2$
where $l_1,l_2\in \mathbb R$. We have that: $$\lim_{x\to x_0}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=\frac {l_1}{l_2}=\frac{f(x_0)}{g(x_0)}=\frac {\lim_{x\to x_0}f(x)}{\lim_{x\to x_0}g(x)}$$
Due to the well known relation : $$\frac{a}{b}=\frac{c}{d}=\frac{a-c}{b-d}$$
Considering the constant functions $h(x)=f(x_0)$ and $k(x)=g(x_0)$
$$\frac {\lim_{x\to x_0}f(x)}{\lim_{x\to x_0}g(x)}=\frac{f(x_0)}{g(x_0)}=\frac {\lim_{x\to x_0}h(x)}{\lim_{x\to x_0}k(x)}=\frac{\lim_{x\to x_0}f(x)- \lim_{x\to x_0}h(x)}{\lim_{x\to x_0}g(x)-\lim_{x\to x_0}k(x)}=\frac{\lim_{x\to x_0}(f(x)-f(x_0))}{\lim_{x\to x_0}(g(x)-g(x_0))}$$

Dividing both the denominator and the numerator by $x-x_0$ we get: $$\frac{\lim_{x\to x_0}(\frac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{x-x_0})}{\lim_{x\to x_0}(\frac{g(x)-g(x_0)}{x-x_0})}=\frac{f(x_0)}{g(x_0)}\Rightarrow \lim_{x\to x_0}\frac {f(x)}{g(x)}=\frac {f'(x_0)}{g'(x_0)}$$ independently of whether $ \lim_{x\to x_0}\frac {f(x)}{g(x)}$ is of the form $\frac{0}{0}$ or $\frac{\pm\infty}{\pm\infty}$
.This is obviously mistaken so I am trying to find where I made the mistake.Can somebody help? Any help is appreciated

Comment: The expression $\frac{lim_{x\to\ x_0}f(x)-lim_{x\to\ x_0}h(x)}{lim_{x\to\ x_0}g(x)-lim_{x\to\ x_0}k(x)}$ is indeterminate since both the numerator and denominator are equal to zero. This makes the steps afterwards meaningless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "well known relation" (namely $\frac{a}{b}=\frac{c}{d}$ implies $\frac{a}{b}=\frac{a-c}{b-d}$) holds for $b\neq 0$, $d\neq 0$ and $b-d\neq 0$ (e.g., consider what happens for $a=b=c=d=1$): this is not the case in your proof, as $\lim_{x\to x_0}g(x)-\lim_{x\to x_0}k(x)=0$.